# Create not nullable column using SQL Server SELECT INTO

Tags: sql-server

RTRIM and LTRIM makes columns to be nullable. How I can make them not nullable?

```
CREATE TABLE SO_IN
(
    RAW NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
) ;
GO

SELECT
    RAW,
    RTRIM(RAW) AS RTRIM,
    LTRIM(RAW) AS LTRIM
INTO SO_OUT
FROM
    SO_IN;

SELECT COLUMN_NAME, IS_NULLABLE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'SO_OUT'
```

The output will be:

```
COLUMN_NAME|IS_NULLABLE
-----------|-----------
RAW        |NO
RTRIM      |YES
LTRIM      |YES
```

I want them to be all IS_NULLABLE NO

Comment: Would it be possible to alter the created table afterwards? Or are there any reasons not to do it that way?

Comment: You can use `coalesce()` with some dummy value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more simple then I thought:

```
CREATE TABLE SO_IN
(
    RAW NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
) ;
GO

SELECT
    RAW,
    ISNULL(RTRIM(RAW),'') AS RTRIM,
    LTRIM(RAW) AS LTRIM
INTO SO_OUT
FROM
    SO_IN;

SELECT COLUMN_NAME, IS_NULLABLE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'SO_OUT'
```

Comment: Do you know why RTRIM alone is not good enaugh?

Comment: Excuse me, "good enough" for what? I left third field for illustration of NULL-ability deliberately

Comment: Let me rephrase it. Do you know why SQL engine considers that column NULLABLE? Why I need to wrap it by IS NULL?

Comment: Ha! It's simple: because `RTRIM(NULL)` will be `NULL`. Maybe you came from oracle? In oracle empty string equals to NULL (and I think sometimes that it's an 'incorrect in theory, correct in practice' decision)

Comment: I understand. In my case that cannot be true, because RAW is NOT NULL, but that is too hard for SQL Server to deduce.

Answer (score 1):

You have to apply [ISNULL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql) to make it as Non-nullable field for SELECT * INTO.

```
CREATE TABLE SO_IN
(
    RAW NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
) ;
GO

SELECT
    RAW,
    ISNULL(RTRIM(RAW),'') AS RTRIM,
    ISNULL(LTRIM(RAW),'') AS LTRIM
INTO SO_OUT
FROM
    SO_IN;

SELECT COLUMN_NAME, IS_NULLABLE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'SO_OUT'
```